# Probability question about rolling a dice

Tags: probability

You roll three fair 8-sided dice

a) What is the proability that you get exactly twice a number which is greater than 6?

I did the question and got 3/64 by doing 2/8 x 2/8 x 6/8 but I don't know whether I have to times it by 3 and get 9/64 as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should multiply by $3$, because there are three way to choose the die that will roll 6 or lower.

In general, the probability of rolling exactly $k$ out of $n$ dice higher than $6$ would be:
$$
\binom{n}{k} \cdot \left(\frac 28\right)^k \cdot\left(\frac 68\right)^{n-k}
$$
where the first factor is a binomial coefficient.